# Open Layers 3 disable pinch rotate after map is loaded

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

I would like an option in my application which allows pinch rotate to be disabled when the user desires it.

I have a map:

```
map_object = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
controls: controls_list,
interactions: interactions_list,
overlays: [overlay],
layers: vector_layers,
view: view
});
```

You'll notice that I have defined interactions in the usual way in the map definition.  My interactions_list is as follows:

```
var interactions_list = ol.interaction.defaults({altShiftDragRotate:false, pinchRotate:true, dragPan:true});
```

How do I disable pinch rotate after the map object has been created so that map rotation is disabled *after* the map is loaded and displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use OpenLayers v3.1.1 you can enable/disable an interaction by calling `setActive(true)`/`setActive(false)` on the interaction.

First you need to find the `PinchRotate` interaction in the interactions collection:

```js
var interactions = map.getInteractions().getArray();
var pinchRotateInteraction = interactions.filter(function(interaction) {
  return interaction instanceof ol.interaction.PinchRotate;
})[0];
```

You can then enable and disable the interaction as needed:

```js
pinchRotateInteraction.setActive(false);
pinchRotateInteraction.setActive(true);
```